# Remove Manage external Account button permission

Tags: administration, permissions, profile

For one of the profile who do not have "Manage external Accounts" and do not have "Edit Self-Service Users" permission but still they can "Enable/Disable Partner Accounts".

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Check if the user have some Permission Set that enables him to Manage Users.
Check all the permission set of your user who have this "issue".

Go in:
Setup->Manage Users->Permission Sets->*PERMISSION_SET_NAME*->System Permissions->Edit

Remove flag from "Manage Users", in the "Users" section.

Login as the user and check if the button is still there.

Comment: But will that make them unable to Manage internal users as well?

Comment: Could you please guide on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43160478/unable-to-see-the-manager-external-user-option-how-to-enable-it-in-salesforce